# Findbugs issues with mutability of Date object in Java

Tags: java, coding-style, findbugs

This is more of a follow-up to questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732789/malicious-code-ei-expose-rep-medium) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472299/suppressing-java-findbugs-error-ei-expose-rep).

As told in the questions the below code

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
   return someDate;
}
```

will give you the findbug error [issue](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EI_EXPOSE_REP).

The suggested solution was to duplicate the Date object in both getters and setters like

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
  return new Date(someDate.getTime());
}
```

Is this a good approach or are there any alternative ways to this?

Is there any Immutable Date library available in java that can overcome this issue?

Comment: you mean immutable right? anyhow, the stated approach is perfect.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: thanks and Yes. I have updated the Qs. You means to say its ok to use the Date constructor in all the getters and setter?

Comment: As long as you don't expose the calls to external library. you don't need to deep clone(constructor) it because you know what you do. Otherwise always give the difference reference if it is mutable. Try joda time api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) has immutable dates.

Sure, it's okay to use a `Date` constructor in a getter, why wouldn't it be?

That said, just because FindBugs pegs mutable state as a potential error, it doesn't mean it's intrinsically worth caring about–it depends on how the class is being used. Immutability eliminates one type of bug, which you may or may not need to care a lot about.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of bug it eliminates?

Comment: @TomDane ... The kind where something mutates your state out from under you. This isn't unique to `Date`, it's the same as with *anything* that lets you mutate internal state.

Answer (score 8):

Attention Folks...

besides adapting both the getter and the setter you need to take care about null values:

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
  if (this.someDate == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return new Date(this.someDate.getTime());
}

public void setSomeDate(final Date someDate) {
  if (someDate == null) {
    this.someDate = null;
  } else{
  this.someDate = new Date(someDate.getTime());
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope not. I hope you know for a fact that `someDate` isn’t null and that passing null to the setter is to be considered an error. The defensive copying even gives us the null check for free.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you use-case you could return `someDate.getTime()` without wrapping it in a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute... by copying the object within the `getSomeDate` and `setSomeDate` methods we are not eliminating the security risk since the changed object comes back through the `setSomeDate` and copies preserve the changed values. It would be necessary to remove `setSomeDate` in order to solve this kind of security issue, or do not worry at all about it.

Comment: By returning a copy of the object, we avoid the internal representation being shared - it will help avoiding situations where the calling code (even if it receives this property to a local variable) manipulates this, the bean property will be changed. To state the obvious, setsomeDate cannot be removed as that's the fundamental bean behaviour.