# Final classes in Java which shouldn't be final or vice versa?

Tags: java, class, final

I was asked this question in an interview recently:

> Can you name any class in the Java API that is final that shouldn't be or one that isn't and should be'?

I couldn't think of any. The question implies that I should know all the API classes like the back of my hand, which I personally wouldn't expect any Java developer to know.

If anyone knows any such classes, please provide examples.

Comment: Probably the test is about your experience with Java API, it doesn't mean that you should know it by heart.

Comment: At some points, mainly when debugging horrible code, I would suggest that `Object` should have been made final.

Comment: You didn't make it clear what question you want to ask. Are you looking for an example, or opinion on the interview question, or else?

Comment: what did you answer to the panelist?

Comment: @DDK, my answer was pretty similar to Anony-Moussse, except I couldn't come up with the BitSet class.

Comment: @Quoi, you have no idea how wrong you are. AtomicInteger, AtomicLong SHOULD NOT be final. Collection framework being final would be beyond a terrible idea and stuff like JDO would not be implemented.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first examples that come to mind are some of the non-final Number subclasses, such as [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which should probably have been final.

In particular, all of their methods can be overriden. That enables you to create a broken `BigDecimal`, for example:

```
public class BrokenBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {
    public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend) {
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
}
```

That could create significant issues if you receive BigDecimal from an untrusted code for example.

To paraphrase Effective Java:

- Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it
- Classes should be immutable unless there's a very good reason to make them mutable

Comment: You can design broken list/collection/etc, BigDecimal,BigInteger are ok not being final imo. You can track them if you want to. Being final won't help anything in their case.

Answer (score 22):

`java.awt.Dimension` isn't final or immutable and should have been.   Anything that returns a Dimension (e.g a Window object) needs to make defensive copies to prevent callers from doing nasty things.

Comment: It's not immutable due to  in the days of old, creating new objects (and subsequent GC) was not exactly cheap, likewise Point/Rectangle. Those classes should been value type alike but at the moment java lack such provision.

Comment: Unfortunately it was an invalid optimisation.  Leaving it mutable meant the necessity to create defensive copies that leave to increased allocation/garbage not less.

Comment: How so? you pass the dimension as parameter, that was the idea. Also the copies are necessary only to client-space code, inside the awt the object is accessed by its fields (no copies). I do not defend leaving public fields of dimension, though.. just explaining - making it final would not have helped on its own.

Comment: Have a look at the `size()` method on `java.awt.Component` it copies the Dimension object every time it is called.  You're right making it final is a necessary but not sufficient condition for immutability.

Comment: `size()`, itself, is deprecated, so I suppose you meant `getSize()`. Look at the right method: `Dimension size(Dimension rv)` - this is what I mean. That was the design philosophy - pass the object to be filled in, if you pass null you get brand new object.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, your reply should have been that it is **a matter of taste** which classes should be final and which shouldn't.

There are good reasons to make `Integer`, `Double` and `String` all `final`.

There are good reasons to complain about this.

Then there is `BitSet`, `BitInteger` etc. which could be made `final`.

There are a number of situations where classes are not `final`, but they also cannot be extended reasonably, so they probably should have been made final.

To pick on a particular class: `BitSet`. It is not `final`, yet you cannot extend it to add a bit `shift` operation. They might as well have made it `final` then, or allow us to add such functionality.

Comment: I don't think it is only a matter of taste - Many security features of the Java programming language depend upon String objects being immutable for example. And if you want mutability, you have the mutable companion class, StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` class leaps out. It is a mutable simple value class (essentially a wrapper around a `long`), but a good heuristic is that simple value classes should be immutable. Note also its numerous deprecated methods: more evidence that the design was botched. The mutability of the `Date` is [a source of bugs, requiring disciplined defensive copying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7932489/545127).

Comment: Data class is sublcassed by java.sql.Date/Time/Timestamp, being final won't help as it has setter methods. Actually being non-final is good as you can override the setters and throw UnsupportedOperationException, making the class immutable.

Comment: @bestsss "as it has setter methods": the point is, `Date` should not have setter methods.

Comment: the question is about being final, not about being immutable on its right own. When `Date` was firstly introduced, there was no Calendar and making it immutable later was no-go. So if you want immutable Date, just create one - i.e. make it final and forbid the setters.

Answer (score 0):

*one that isn't and should be*

Most final classes in java are designed so due w/ security considerations in mind, overall there are relatively few final ones. For instance `java.util.String` is final for that very reason. So are many others.
Some classes w/ private c-tor are declared final (Math, StrictMath) but it doesn't matter in such a case.

Basically unless there are security issues involved I don't care if the class is final, yet you can always use non-public c-tor w/ some factory, effectively limiting the ability to subclass. Usually that's my preferred way as it allows package-private subclassing.

In short: I can't think of a final class that should not be, however there are some that could potentially have been. For instance `java.lang.Thread` being final might have not needed to protect vs malicious `clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.Collections` should be declared final.

Here is why:

1. They contain only static members *and a private constructor*.
2. The private constructor prevents those classes from being extended.

So, those classes cannot be extended, but this fact is not visible in their public interface. Declaring them `final` would expose it and clarify intent.

Additionally, `java.lang.Math` (another so-called *utility class*) has the same structure and it is also declared `final`.

Answer (score -2):

Check the String class which is final and probably should had been your answer in the interview.

Check the docs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Why should it be *not* final?

Comment: Well, .NET's [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is *also* final *and* immutable, like Java's.

Comment: Out of curiosity; what would be your reasoning for saying it shouldn't be final? Since you say it's _obvious_. ;)

Comment: I didnt say it shouldnt be final.

Comment: Erm, yes you did (or else why did you suggest it as an example?)

Comment: Question was - Can you name any class in the Java API that is final that shouldn't be or one that isn't and should be?

Comment: @SerdarDogruyol you may want to *reread* the questions. It's about classes where `final` is not well used.